# Why I'm getting "Invalid column name 'Table_TableId' (Foreign Keys already configured with Fluent API)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm refactoring code from an existing project (.NET with C#)... I'm using Reverse POCO to generate models and configure the Foreign Keys (it's a very large database).

Everything goes ok until I try to query a table... The model generated by Reverse POCO contains this FKs (refering to Customer table):

```
 public virtual Customer Customer_CustomerId { get; set; } 
 public virtual Customer Customer1 { get; set; } 
 public virtual Customer MatchingCustomer { get; set; }
```

But when I try to select with LINQ, an exception is thrown:

> Invalid column name 'Customer_CustomerId'

From what I've read, all I need is to map the FKs with Fluent API... Reverse POCO also gave me the configuration files for each Model, this is the Configuration for those FKs

```
 HasOptional(a => a.Customer_CustomerId).WithMany(b => b.MapCustomerMatches_CustomerId).HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 HasOptional(a => a.Customer1).WithMany(b => b.MapCustomerMatches1).HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
 HasOptional(a => a.MatchingCustomer).WithMany(b => b.MatchingCustomer).HasForeignKey(c => c.MatchingCustomerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I don't know why it's happening...

Comment: Customer_CustomerId isn't a FK - it's a navigation property which you can Include() in your query. What's your query look like?

Comment: `code`customer.Matches = await ctx.MapCustomerMatches.Where(m => m.MatchingCustomerId == CustomerID).ToListAsync();`code`
ctx is my Context

Answer (score 0):

EF relation should be defined in two models, but you've got only one.

> Error: Invalid column name 'Category_CategoryID'.

This is EF-generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[SubtypeID] AS [SubtypeID], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Extent1].[Category_CategoryID] AS [Category_CategoryID] -- <- here 1
    FROM [dbo].[Subtypes] AS [Extent1]
```

Reason of the error: Sybtype is referenced from Category entity (uncomment ICollection to reproduce the issue):

```
public sealed class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    // uncomment this line to reproduce the issue
    // public ICollection<Subtype> Subtypes { get; set; } //<- here 2
}
```

But Subtype does not refer to Category, it refers to Suppliers:

```
public class Subtype : BaseModel
{
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public int? SupplierID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    // Here is what is expected from EF (two side relation, but you've got only one)
    // public virtual Category Category  { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; } //<- here 3
}

public sealed class Supplier
{
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subtype> Subtypes { get; set; }
}
```

---

Fluent API information might be helpful as well here:

```
public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.CategoryID);
        ToTable("Categories");
        Property(t => t.CategoryID).HasColumnName("CategoryID");
    }
}

public class SubtypeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subtype>
{
    public SubtypeMap()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
        Property(t => t.SupplierID).HasColumnName("SupplierID");

        HasOptional(t => t.Supplier)
            .WithMany(t => t.Subtypes)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.SupplierID);
    }
}
```